# How to substitute newline character \n with two characters \r\n using VIM

Tags: vim

I have a text file which contains \n (0x0A) at the end of line, but as windows (notepad) take two characters i.e. \r\n (0x0D0A) to identify end of line therefor i want to substitute \n with these two characters \r\n.

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
:set ff=dos
:w
```

[`ff`/`fileformat` is "unix" by default, but CRLF terminators are used when it is "dos"](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27fileformat%27). All line endings will be changed when the file is written back. See `:help ff` for further caveats and corner cases.

Comment: @Nouman if this answer works for you please remember to accept it with the tick mark on its left, next to the up/down voting buttons.